# Display Bluedot Menu contents?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>

<script>
 intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '/path/to/blue-dot', grantUrl: "<%= authenticate_settings_url %>"});
</script>

<body>
 <ipp:blueDot></ipp:blueDot>
</body>
```

It is displaying bluedot menu on the top of my application but not displaying the companies that i am connected with. Insteed, it is displaying something like "We are sorry but we cannot load the menu right now".

I want to display the companies list that I am connected with in this blue dot menu. I think i am missing path of munuProxy :

`menuProxy: '/path/to/blue-dot'`

I have no idea what to do with this. If i have to give path to any bluedotMenu action than what should i write on that action to display list of companies?

How to fix this problem?

[NOTE: I am using Chrome and Firefox as my browser so, i don't think it's my browser problem]

Comment: przbadu, you don't need to set the title to "solved" in questions and answers. Just check the green ✓ mark left of the answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session to store tokens and use them whenever required

```
def bluedot
  access_token = session[access_token]
  access_secret = session[access_secret]
  consumer = OAuth::AccessToken.new($qb_oauth_consumer, access_token, access_secret)
  response = consumer.request(:get, "https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Account/AppMenu")
  if response && response.body
   html = response.body
   render(:text => html) and return
  end
end
```

You will get the blue dot menu content from "https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Account/AppMenu" url. before that you need to authenticate your self with valid authentication tokens i.e. session[access_token] and session[access_secret] in this case. and you are all done.

Answer (score 1):

Fault was all mine. Now, I have modified menuProxy to:

```
<script>
 intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '<%= bluedot_settings_url %>', grantUrl: "<%= authenticate_settings_url %>"});
</script>
```

`"We are sorry but we cannot load the menu right now",`

this was displaying because I forgot to create .js file of bluedot action.

Now it is displaying bluedot menu without companies. So, I need a help to load companies in this bluedot menu either from bluedot.js.erb file or bluedot in controller action?

Answer (score 1):

**Display quickbook Blue-Dot Menu contents in rails application**

We need to make an API call to Intuit to fetch the menu proxy contents (and should cache them). Catching will help to load our menu content faster.

**Solution without catching**

1) application.html.erb file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>
<script>
    intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '<%= bluedot_settings_url %>', grantUrl: "<%= authenticate_settings_url %>"});
</script>
<body>
  <ipp:blueDot></ipp:blueDot>
</body>
```

2) settings_controller

```
def bluedot
  # I am saving access_token and access_secret in company table so I will fetch from there
  access_token = current_company.access_token
  access_secret = current_company.access_secret
  consumer = OAuth::AccessToken.new($qb_oauth_consumer, access_token, access_secret)
  response = consumer.request(:get, "https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Account/AppMenu")
  if response && response.body
    html = response.body
    render(:text => html) and return
  end
end
```

That's it........

**[ NOTE: for authentication, connecting to the quickbook or other parts, Please follow [quickeebook gem](https://github.com/ruckus/quickeebooks) easy and simple]**